# Get position of element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Suppose I have a xml

```
<Root>
<TB>
..
</TB>
<TB>
..

</TB>
<TB>
..
<DIACT>2</DIACT>
</TB>
<TB>
...
<DIACT>3</DIACT>
</TB>
<TB>
----
<DIACT>4</DIACT>
---
</TB>
</Root>
```

I want to get the **position** of first TB node where DIACT is not null or DIACT node exist, using xslt mapping. Like in this case postion should give me output as 3. As 3rd TB node is the first one with DIACT not null.

Comment: Can you explain why you want the position of that node?

Comment: Actually I need to do some further processing based upon this position. Sorry but I can't explain the whole scenario. But is there any way so that I can get this.

Comment: From my experience: you almost never need the position of a node to do further processing. It's likely that you're trying to do something the wrong way altogether, so it could be beneficial to explain the scenario.

Comment: Tomalak:- I got the things working. Thanks for your post, i just needed the same thing you posted.

Comment: It's also worth noting that both @Tomalak's and Dimitre's solution assumes that at least one TB[DIACT] exists. If not, a misleading output may result.

Comment: Actually I needed to compare two indexes that's why I needed the value.

Comment: yes Sean.. I got your point. thnx. I appended an if clause to check that atleat one should be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
count(/*/TB[DIACT][1]/preceding-sibling::TB) +1
```

As you need this for futher procesing, set a variable that has the above value:

```
<xsl:variable name="vPos" 
              select="count(/*/TB[DIACT][1]/preceding-sibling::TB) +1"/>
```

**Alternatively, one can use `xsl:number`** :

```
  <xsl:variable name="vPos2">
    <xsl:number count="TB"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

**Here is a simple demo of the two techniques:**

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vPos"
        select="count(/*/TB[DIACT][1]/preceding-sibling::TB) +1"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$vPos"/>
=========== 
    <xsl:for-each select="/*/TB[DIACT][1]">
      <xsl:variable name="vPos2">
        <xsl:number count="TB"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$vPos2"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Root>
    <TB> .. </TB>
    <TB> ..  </TB>
    <TB> .. 
        <DIACT>2</DIACT>
    </TB>
    <TB> ... 
        <DIACT>3</DIACT>
    </TB>
    <TB> ---- 
        <DIACT>4</DIACT> --- 
    </TB>
</Root>
```

**two correct results are produced**:

```
3
=========== 
3
```

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, Of course, and I noticed and fixed this long ago, Sorry for seeing your comment only now.